# Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error. in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, error-handling

I have a function in my AS3 that frequently calls a PHP file. Most of the time it works but occasionally it fails and throws the error I used in the title. I researched this fairly extensively and started capturing the event in the following manner:

```
public static function Bar():void {
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("path/to/file.php");
    var requestVariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

    requestVariables.event = "foo";

    request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    request.data = requestVariables;

    loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
    loader.load(request);
    loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError, false, 0, true);
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onIOComplete, false, 0, true);
}

private static function onIOComplete(e:Event):void
{
    var loader:Loader = e.target as Loader;
    if ( loader != null ) 
    {
        loader.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
        loader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onIOComplete);
    }
    Logger.log("LOADER COMPLETE");
}

private static function onIOError(e:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    var loader:Loader = e.target as Loader;
    if ( loader != null ) 
    {
        loader.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
        loader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onIOComplete);
    }
    Logger.log("ERROR: " + e.toString());
}
```

In spite of the above code, I am still seeing the stream error occasionally. Is there more I should/could be doing?

Comment: Where exactly is the error being thrown? You can run it in debug and step through. First thing that comes to my mind is using try catch blocks, but knowing exactly what line of code is causing the error would be first prioirity.

Comment: could "path/to/file.php" be the problem? Maybe "http : //url/to/file.php" would work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the issue was that the php file I was calling was making a network call using file_get_contents in a case where I should have been using cURL. Once I changed them the second network call stopped failing thus I stopped seeing the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLVariables;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
import flash.display.Loader;

function Bar():void { 
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://127.0.0.1/test.php"); 
    var requestVariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables(); 
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(); 

    requestVariables.event = "foo"; 

    request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST; 
    request.data = requestVariables; 

    loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT; 
    loader.load(request); 
    loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError, false, 0, true); 
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onIOComplete, false, 0, true); 
} 

function onIOComplete(e:Event):void 
{ 
    var loader:Loader = e.target as Loader; 
    if ( loader != null )  
    { 
        loader.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError); 
        loader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onIOComplete); 
    } 
    trace("LOADER COMPLETE"); 
} 

function onIOError(e:IOErrorEvent):void 
{ 
    var loader:Loader = e.target as Loader; 
    if ( loader != null )  
    { 
        loader.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError); 
        loader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onIOComplete); 
    } 
    trace("ERROR: " + e.toString()); 
} 

Bar();
```

I only get LOADER COMPLETE

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing this on localhost, or over a network?  If your network connection to the machine hosting the php file is dropping out, then you can expect an IOErrorEvent.

Comment: Then it's most likely a network issue.  You can use the IOErrorEvent handler to deal with intermittent network connectivity by waiting a short amount of time and sending the request again.  Depending on what you're doing, you might want to keep track of the number of re-loads so that after a certain amount of tries, you can give up and alert the user that the app is unable to contact the server.